# Angular v4.4 app stops loading with an isolated update of a JS module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I received a *hot potato* of an Angular 4.4 application which is quite fragile. When I try to update the auth0-js module the app stops loading and its bootstrap component constructor is never called. It loads the initial html, runs app.module.ts and main.ts. Then it appears to just stop. I've gone through debugging, single-stepping, several times in Chrome & FF developer tools. It just seems to stop. I've put all sorts of console.log statements at loading and constructors of various components and modules. It apparently never calls the constructor of app.component.ts.

I have carefully isolated the changes to required modules from the auth0-js module. There is only one required module, qs, which is also used by my code or any other js modules. The other required modules are only used by auth0-js. I froze the top level qs version and forced npm to install that as a dependency of auth0-js when upgrading. I can find no changes that could cause this breakage.

And, as far as the auth0-js library itself, I have already made use of the latest version in another similar project. And, the code executed before the app just stops does not include any calls to auth0-js. In other words, that code is not touched before the app stops running.

Building is done with the Angular CLI version 1.7.4, installed local to the project (in ./node_modules/). Then it is built/launched via `ng serve --env local`. That server seems a black box with no useful logging. I switched to serving via nginx and building via `ng build --output-hashing=all --env local`. Still not getting any further. Its been several weeks and my forehead is becoming concave. Any and all suggestions are more than welcome.

Here is my main.ts

```js
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  console.log('main.ts: enabling production mode');
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Update: I did not have the .catch call on the bootstrapModule, but I just added it. Now I do see an error message in the console:

> Error: "Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise
>   `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten. Most likely cause is
>   that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling
>   Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load
>   one, do so before loading zone.js.)"

Now I have something to look into further. I will see about updating the zone.js version, and making it the same by updating another library.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng2-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --env local",
    "build-prod": "ng build --output-hashing=all --env prod",
    "build-dev": "ng build --output-hashing=all --env dev",
    "build-staging": "ng build --output-hashing=all --env staging",
    "build-local": "ng build --output-hashing=all --env local",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.6",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.3",
    "angular2-uuid": "1.1.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.13.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "ng2-adal": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-dnd": "4.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.6.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.5.2",
    "qs": "^6.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "shortid": "2.2.8",
    "string-similarity": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-md5": "1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/node": "6.0.68",
    "@types/shortid": "0.0.28",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-only": "^0.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.3.0",
    "karma": "1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.2",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: too much text, no code, no packages.json, likely to be closed

Comment: I added my package.json. Not all code can be shared and what would I actually provide for this huge project?

4 paragraphs of text is too much? Don't you handle reading English? I think this is a rather harsh response. I'm not actually expecting someone to tell me what is wrong with the code, but how they would attack this problem. So imagine you had all the code before you: what would you do next?

Comment: Ok, let's go. First, there are any error messages on console? If yes, please post it. Also, you don't need to place the full code, but only relevant parts. Probably you should post the code for some service/provider that uses the Auth0 library. Also, post the auth0 version before and after the npm upgrade. With this version in hand you can go to Auth0 changelog and read the changes between the versions (looking for breaking changes initially).

Comment: There are no error messages on the console. It just quietly runs all JS code queued and stops.

Auth0-js was upgraded from 9.4.2 to 9.13.2. As I mentioned, there is no execution of any code that uses auth0. The provider for authentication never gets called, because the application never truly gets booted. 

I also mentioned that I did a similar upgrade of auth0-js in another Angular application which is similar. There were no issues with auth0 upgrade.

Comment: I now have an error message, with which I have updated my question. And I indicated the direction I am trying to move forward.

Comment: Try removing your import to polyfills... I don't think it's needed since angular cli will polyfill automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensuring that exceptions from the platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule() call are caught is essential to indentify errors.

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

And the resulting error message:

> Error: "Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise
>   `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten. Most likely cause is
>   that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling
>   Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load
>   one, do so before loading zone.js.)"

points to an issue with different definitions of ZoneAwarePromise. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11650 .

Update some npm modules:

```sh
npm install --save ng2-adal@2.0.0
npm install --save zone.js@0.8
```

and you will have closer versions of zone.js. That allows the Angular app to get bootstrapped.